# What is happening in issue #1 of "Black Magick"?

Tags: comics, greg-rucka, black-magick

The first issue of *Black Magick* opens with a pagan ritual being done during full moon. A circle member's phone rings, and the ritual is interrupted, and the following panels take place (behind a spoiler because there is *some* nudity there, but not too much):

> [image]

I should also note that those two women really are witches.

Two questions:

1. What does the gesture with the knife mean? Was it meant to be intimidation, or is it some ritualistic thing?
2. The woman with the knife says

   > Make sure you **ground** yourself before you leave.

   What is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

Grounding is creating balance and stability in yourself

- both before you receive and transfer energy when casting a spell or healing
- and also afterwards, either by shedding excess energy or by replenishing, for example from the earth

Comment: Is this a pagan practice, or a witching practice, or..?

Comment: It is both, but doesn't have to be either.

Comment: That's interesting. Is there any further reading on this? Also, what does she do with the ritual knife?

Comment: @Gallifreyan: The knife is known as an *Athame*.  Each witch will create her own so that is imbued with her energy.  There are several books available, you shouldn't have trouble finding one.

Comment: @Chenmunka What would I search for title-wise? I'm guessing there's no "Witchcraft for Dummies".